# using functions of an implemented interface creates 'not a function' error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I defined an interface with variables and a function.

When trying to use the function implemented for a class I get 'ERROR TypeError: ...getPrice is not a function"

The definition of the class and interface:

```
export interface Charge {
  code: string;
  name: string;

  getPrice: (category: string) => number;
}

export class StorePrice implements Charge {
  code: string;
  name: string;

  getPrice(category: string): number {
    return 234;
  }
}
```

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  charges: Charge[];

  constructor() {
    this.charges = [
      {
        code: "125",
        name: "apple"
      } as StorePrice,
    ];
  }

  asStorePrice(charge: Charge) {
    return charge as StorePrice;
  }
}
```

The HTML where I actually use the function:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let charge of charges">

  {{asStorePrice(charge).getPrice()}}

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as i know `as` wont change the prototype of the object. So there is not getPrice on a plain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is this:

```
this.charges = [
  {
    code: "125",
    name: "apple"
  } as StorePrice,
];
```

You could create an Object of StorePrice :

```
new StorePrice('125', 'apple');
```

with:

```
export class StorePrice implements Charge {

  constructor(
      public code: string,
      public name: string
  ) {}

  getPrice(category: string): number {
    return 234;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the 'as' use. 'as' is just an other syntax of the cast

```
<StorePrice> yourVariable;
```

Using, 'as' doesnt create an object of the class. If you want to get the getPrice function on your object, then you need to instantiate the object normally:

```
this.charges = [
  new StorePrice("125, "apple)
]
```

Ofc, you need to create the constructor in the class.